# How to set SameSite attribute to 'None; Secure' in Rails3.1.12 and Ruby1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9.2

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://example.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Please let me know how to set the SameSite cookie attribute. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post some more context about the scenario where you are getting this warning in Chrome console. Is it a part of your code or some 3rd party library that is trying to set a cookie ?

Comment: We have set of appications(more than 3). All the applications are embeded as a iframe in an applicaiton and able to access using the secure token and works fine on all the browsers. 

But, the mentioned issue is coming in "Google Chrome Canary" and not able to access the embedded appliations. For that, I Plan to add SameSite cookie.

Answer (score 18):

In Rails 6.0 and 6.1 the [`same_site` attribute has been added](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28297):

```
cookies["foo"] = {
  value: "bar",
  secure: Rails.application.config.secure_cookies,
  same_site: "None"
}
```

For Rails 5.x and lower, the [`rails_same_site_cookie`](https://github.com/pschinis/rails_same_site_cookie) gem is a good option for adding `SameSite=None;` to all your app's cookies.  It uses middleware to do it.

Comment: Setting `cookies["foo"] = {value: "bar", same_site: :none, secure: true}` worked for me in Rails 5.2.3, though apparently [you need Rack >= 2.1.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/28297#issuecomment-600566751)

Answer (score 7):

The way to set custom headers is to add the line below to your controller action:

`response.headers['Set-Cookie'] = 'Secure;SameSite=None'`.

Comment: Please **do not** blanket add `SameSite=None` to all your cookies. This explicitly marks your cookies as being for cross-site delivery and is probably not what you want. You lose the security benefits of the CSRF protection that the new defaults provide. Consider adding `SameSite=Lax` as your default and **only** use `SameSite=None` when you **need** a cross-site cookie. More information on https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained

Answer (score 5):

Action dispatch [cookies](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb) is responsible for writing cookies to browser set in application, this uses `Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!`.

Support for `SameSite` has been added after rack version 1.6, you need to check your rack version in Gemfile and if it is < 1.6 you need to add the following code in `config/initializers`

```
require 'rack/utils'
module Rack
  module Utils
    def self.set_cookie_header!(header, key, value)
      case value
      when Hash
        domain  = "; domain="  + value[:domain] if value[:domain]
        path    = "; path="    + value[:path]   if value[:path]
        max_age = "; max-age=" + value[:max_age] if value[:max_age]
        expires = "; expires=" +
          rfc2822(value[:expires].clone.gmtime) if value[:expires]
        secure = "; secure"  if value[:secure]
        httponly = "; HttpOnly" if value[:httponly]
        same_site =
          case value[:same_site]
          when false, nil
            nil
          when :none, 'None', :None
            '; SameSite=None'
          when :lax, 'Lax', :Lax
            '; SameSite=Lax'
          when true, :strict, 'Strict', :Strict
            '; SameSite=Strict'
          else
            raise ArgumentError, "Invalid SameSite value: #{value[:same_site].inspect}"
          end
        value = value[:value]
      end
      value = [value] unless Array === value
      cookie = escape(key) + "=" +
        value.map { |v| escape v }.join("&") +
        "#{domain}#{path}#{max_age}#{expires}#{secure}#{httponly}#{same_site}"

      case header["Set-Cookie"]
      when nil, ''
        header["Set-Cookie"] = cookie
      when String
        header["Set-Cookie"] = [header["Set-Cookie"], cookie].join("\n")
      when Array
        header["Set-Cookie"] = (header["Set-Cookie"] + [cookie]).join("\n")
      end

      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Once done you can set `SameSite` attribute while creating a new cookie, for ex:

```
cookies['testing'] = {
  value: 'test',
  path: '/',
  expiry: 1.weeks.from_now,
  same_site: :none
}
```

you can also add the `same_site: <value>` to your session store as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't see SameSite=None in rack 1.6.11 implementation, so I believe we need to monkey patch that version too?

Comment: yes, if the support is not present we need to add the patch.

Comment: Just FYI, looks like the earliest rack version that supports setting SameSite=None is 2.1.0: https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/c859bbf7b53cb59df1837612a8c330dfb4147392, while `Lax` or `Secure` is supported in 2.0.0: https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/f0f828cc1499cf54495e545daecb992a21fef324

Answer (score 1):

What I did is the following:
In `session_store.rb` I configured:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cache_store, key: COOKIE_NAME, :expire_after => 1.days, :expires_in => 1.days, :domain => 'mydomain.com', same_site: :none
```

And I added this monkey patch:

```
require 'rack/utils'
module Rack
  module Utils
    def self.set_cookie_header!(header, key, value)
      case value
      when Hash
        domain  = "; domain="  + value[:domain] if value[:domain]
        path    = "; path="    + value[:path]   if value[:path]
        max_age = "; max-age=" + value[:max_age] if value[:max_age]
        expires = "; expires=" +
            rfc2822(value[:expires].clone.gmtime) if value[:expires]

        # Make it always secure, even in HTTP
        # secure = "; secure"  if value[:secure]
        secure = "; secure"

        httponly = "; HttpOnly" if value[:httponly]
        same_site =
            case value[:same_site]
            when false, nil
              nil
            when :none, 'None', :None
              '; SameSite=None'
            when :lax, 'Lax', :Lax
              '; SameSite=Lax'
            when true, :strict, 'Strict', :Strict
              '; SameSite=Strict'
            else
              raise ArgumentError, "Invalid SameSite value: #{value[:same_site].inspect}"
            end
        value = value[:value]
      end
      value = [value] unless Array === value
      cookie = escape(key) + "=" +
          value.map { |v| escape v }.join("&") +
          "#{domain}#{path}#{max_age}#{expires}#{secure}#{httponly}#{same_site}"

      case header["Set-Cookie"]
      when nil, ''
        header["Set-Cookie"] = cookie
      when String
        header["Set-Cookie"] = [header["Set-Cookie"], cookie].join("\n")
      when Array
        header["Set-Cookie"] = (header["Set-Cookie"] + [cookie]).join("\n")
      end

      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

A backport of fixes to rack was contributed here.

https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/1547

It won't be released, so you'll likely need to use a fork of rack in your `Gemfile`.

https://bundler.io/v1.17/guides/git.html

Answer (score -1):

**Rails 6.0:**

```
cookies[:foo] = {
    value: "bar",
    secure: true,
    same_site: :none
}
```

You gotta take care when you are testing it cause it will only works on production/staging environment when you have the HTTPS running. You wont be able to test it on development.