# Maintain session created from iFrame [Devise + Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, devise

I run a video application in which videos are embedded through an `iframe`. If a video is private, sign in is needed, and I currently redirect them to the sign-in page on my domain and then back to the video once complete.

I want users to be able to log in from an embedded `iframe` and to have their session remain active, without having to navigate to another page.

I have AJAX sign in working from the sign-in page on my domain. However, when try to do this from the `iframe`, authentication succeeds, but the session is not maintained and rails believes there is no current user upon reload.

My configuration allows iframes to be used anywhere:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
}
```

And I do not require an authenticity token for the sign in action.

How can I create and maintain a session from within an `iframe`?

**Edit**: The session saves in Firefox, but Chrome, Safari, and Brave don't maintain it. Not sure why this is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094712/iframe-not-reading-cookies-in-chrome

Comment: "The session saves in Firefox, but Chrome, Safari, and Brave don't maintain it. Not sure why this is.". Because iframes are a security nightmare and browsers have counter measures against clickjacking, tracking and other nefarious behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @max. Do you think this is unachievable in that case?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure this out, I'm facing the exact same issue, a vendor hosts features inside an iFrame and I can't get the session to be maintained.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not @Stewart.

Comment: ah well, thanks for replying though mate! :thumbsup:

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4.2, I followed this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60036434/4607290. Essentially you have to override the `set_cookie_header!` method by creating an initializer.

Then I had to modify my `session_store` so it set the SameSite cookie to None/Secure: https://www.skcript.com/svr/samesite-issue-with-rails-in-chrome/

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  :key => '_application_session',
  :domain => :all,
  :same_site => :none,
  :secure => :true,
  :tld_length => 2
}
```

Hope that helps anyone who stumbled across this post like I did. **NOTE: Changing these settings have security ramifications and should be done only if you know what you're doing.**

Comment: this does't works, throws "InvalidAuthenticityToken" error on login